# how to make chef execute with a specific user and load its environment values

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Hi I am creating a WCS instance, for which i have to execute the create instance command using the wcs user (webadmin), its failing to connect to DB as its not able to get the required env variables.

**so i put some sample code to check**

I am using the below code

```
bash "wcs-create-instance" do
    user "webadmin"
    group "webspher"
    code <<-EOH        
        ###{node[:websphere][:wcs][:wcs_installLocation]}/bin/config_ant.sh -DinstanceName=#{node[:websphere][:wcs][:wcs_instance]} CreateInstance  
    whoami > /tmp/whoami
    env > /tmp/env              
EOH
    notifies :run, "bash[fix-permission]", :immediately 
    #This not_if is just temporary, a proper mechanism has to be implemented here to loop through all the WCS APars,
    #For the POC keeping it neat and simple such that this does not rerun on execution
    not_if {File.directory?("#{node[:websphere][:wcs][:wcs_installLocation]}/instances/#{node[:websphere][:wcs][:wcs_instance]}/starterstores")}
    #action :nothing
end
```

For whoami i am getting the user

> webadmin

But for env i am getting the env of the user "root", its not sourcing the .bash_profile for the env variables. Any ideas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an `environment` attribute in the [`bash` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_bash.html). Or you can source the .bash_profile in the script. That's [one of the things you can do with bash](https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html#examples) (last example)

Comment: tried to source but its not working, given there are quite a few environment variables to set, setting it while running the command in bash resource would be very cumbersome.

Comment: Seems that i was doing something wrong, the solution suggested by Paulo is the correct one, i did source the .bash_profile (this time properly) and it was working fine. Thanks again

Comment: @Saurav   You mentioned you sourced .bash_profile properly. Can you tell me how? Even I am facing problem with sourcing bash_profile

Comment: @VinayKadalagi follow the link which Paulo has suggested.

bash 'foo' do
  code 'source /tmp/foo.sh'
end

Comment: Or you can use this using the environment attribute

execute "wcs-create-instance" do
  user node['was']['usr']
  group node['was']['usr_grp']
  cwd "#{node['wcs']['wcs_installLocation']}/bin"
  environment(
    'ORACLE_HOME' => '#{node["ora_client"]["home"]}/product/#{node["ora_client"]["version"]}',
    'TNS_ADMIN' => node["ora_client"]["tns_home"]
  )
  command "./config_ant.sh -DinstanceName=#{node['wcs']['wcs_instance']} CreateInstance"  
  not_if {File.exists?("#{node['wcs']['wcs_installLocation']}/instances/#{node['wcs']['wcs_instance']}/web/index.html")}
end

Answer (score -1):

Seems like adding `flags '-l'` to tell bash to act as a login shell also does the trick.

```
bash 'do something' do
  code 'my_command'
  flags '-l'
end
```

Or using the `execute` block:

```
execute 'foo' do
  command 'bash -l -c "my_command"'
end
```