# cant get chef to run bash under a certain user

Tags: bash, chef-infra

Given the following chef cookbook snippet:

```
bash "source a file" do
  user "someUser"
  cwd "/tmp"
  code <<-EOH
source /tmp/test.sh
  EOH
end
```

where /tmp/test.sh contains:

```
echo $USER >> /tmp/out.log
```

/tmp/out.log then contains "root" not "someUser"

This is causing issues for me since I need all source and bash commands to run as someUser.

Answer (score 17):

Something I had to learn the hard way with Chef: It may actually be running as the user, but the **environment variables aren't set**.

To see this for yourself, run

```
echo `whoami`
```

If you need the environment variables set, just set them (or source a `.bash_profile`):

```
bash "source a file" do
  user "someUser"
  cwd "/tmp"
  environment ({'HOME' => '/home/someUser', 'USER' => 'someUser'})
  code <<-EOH
source /tmp/test.sh
  EOH
end
```

As a side note, have you created the user?

Comment: definitely spot on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614372/how-to-make-chef-execute-with-a-specific-user-and-load-its-environment-values